# Javascript issues form values and windows

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form where a user enters a username, and then clicks a button. Then it opens a window with the parameters in the url like so below.

```
<script type="javascript">
function open(id) {
    window.open("http://linkhere.com/~Robby/lcpVote.php?u="+ document.getElementById(id).innerHTML +"&s=" + id + "&a=addVote");
}
</script>
<input type="text" placeholder="MC Username" id="name" style="width:100%">
```

And when they click on the button below,

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" onclick="open('1')" id="1" href="#">MCServers.org</button>
```

It opens the following url

```
http://LINKHERE.COM/~Robby/lcpVote.php?u=USERNAMEFROMFORM&s=IDFROMBUTTON&a=addVote
```

But when I click it using my code it just returns a white page?

Comment: Is that HTML5? Otherwise numeric id is not allowed. Also, you're not properly escaping your query string parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm absolutely TERRIBLE with javascript.

Comment: Why don't you just use a form using the get method?

Comment: I'm really stupid, thanks!

Comment: Also please...for the future of htmls purpose, please end your input tag as  /> rather than just > hahaha

Comment: @clockwork189 You have to close input tags only in XHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `method="get"` on the form. This will make the query string suitable to what you want depending on the input names within your form.

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are passing in 1 as an id in your onclick function. You should instead pass in the id of the input field. So it should be:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" onclick="open('name')" id="1" href="#">MCServers.org</button>
```

Where **name** is your input fields id.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `innerHTML` by `value`..

```
window.open("http://linkhere.com/~Robby/lcpVote.php?u="+ document.getElementById(id).value+"&s=" + id + "&a=addVote");
```

and replace `1` by `name`..

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" onclick="open('name')" id="1" href="#">MCServers.org</button>
```